# Dividing columns containing NA

Tags: r, dplyr, na, missing-data

I'm trying to divide two columns both containing NA's, but can't make it work.

I've tried this:

```
df%>%
mutate(c_n = c / n, na.rm = TRUE)
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting? NA divided by anything, including another NA, is NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simply

```
df%>%
mutate(c_n = c / n)
```

NAs will automatically be left as they are

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep `NA`s, you can try

```
df %>%
  mutate(c_n = C / N)
```